# Concrete5 Upgrade Update error

Tags: php, upgrade, updates, concrete5

I am getting the following error when upgrading from 5.6.1.2 to 5.6.3.2. Does anyone know what the issue is?

An Unexpected Error occurred while upgrading: #0 /home8/peacefy7/public_html/staging/updates/concrete5.6.3.2/concrete/libraries/3rdparty/adodb/adodb.inc.php(641): adodb_throw('mysqlt', 'DOQUOTE', -9999, 'Numeric field t...', '', false, Object(ADODB_mysqlt)) #1 /home8/peacefy7/public_html/staging/updates/concrete5.6.3.2/concrete/core/libraries/model.php(44): ADOConnection->outp_throw('Numeric field t...', 'DOQUOTE') #2 /home8/peacefy7/public_html/staging/updates/concrete5.6.3.2/concrete/libraries/3rdparty/adodb/adodb-active-record.inc.php(845): Concrete5_Library_Model->doquote(Object(ADODB_mysqlt), true, 'I') #3 /home8/peacefy7/public_html/staging/updates/concrete5.6.3.2/concrete/core/models/block_types.php(763): ADODB_Active_Record->Replace() #4 /home8/peacefy7/public_html/staging/updates/concrete5.6.3.2/concrete/core/models/block_types.php(671): Concrete5_Model_BlockType->doInstallBlockType('guestbook', Object(BlockType), '/home8/peacefy7...', '16', '/home8/peacefy7...') #5 /home8/peacefy7/public_html/staging/updates/concrete5.6.3.2/concrete/core/models/block_types.php(632): Concrete5_Model_BlockType->installBlockType('guestbook', '16') #6 /home8/peacefy7/public_html/staging/updates/concrete5.6.3.2/concrete/helpers/concrete/upgrade/version_563.php(17): Concrete5_Model_BlockType->refresh() #7 /home8/peacefy7/public_html/staging/updates/concrete5.6.3.2/concrete/core/controllers/single_pages/upgrade.php(272): ConcreteUpgradeVersion563Helper->run() #8 /home8/peacefy7/public_html/staging/updates/concrete5.6.3.2/concrete/core/controllers/single_pages/upgrade.php(64): Concrete5_Controller_Upgrade->do_upgrade() #9 /home8/peacefy7/public_html/staging/updates/concrete5.6.3.2/concrete/core/libraries/controller.php(267): Concrete5_Controller_Upgrade->view('tools', 'required', 'upgrade.php') #10 /home8/peacefy7/public_html/staging/updates/concrete5.6.3.2/concrete/core/libraries/controller.php(237): Concrete5_Library_Controller->runTask(Array, Array) #11 /home8/peacefy7/public_html/staging/updates/concrete5.6.3.2/concrete/core/libraries/view.php(787): Concrete5_Library_Controller->setupAndRun('view', Array) #12 /home8/peacefy7/public_html/staging/updates/concrete5.6.3.2/concrete/tools/upgrade.php(6): Concrete5_Library_View->render() #13 /home8/peacefy7/public_html/staging/updates/concrete5.6.3.2/concrete/startup/tools_upgrade_check.php(9): include('/home8/peacefy7...') #14 /home8/peacefy7/public_html/staging/updates/concrete5.6.3.2/concrete/dispatcher.php(105): require('/home8/peacefy7...') #15 /home8/peacefy7/public_html/staging/concrete/startup/updated_core_check.php(6): require('/home8/peacefy7...') #16 /home8/peacefy7/public_html/staging/concrete/dispatcher.php(20): require('/home8/peacefy7...') #17 /home8/peacefy7/public_html/staging/index.php(2): require('/home8/peacefy7...') #18 {main}

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out! For anyone wondering:

> Exact same error trying to upgrade from 5.6.1.2 to 5.6.3 (or directly
>   to 5.6.3.2)
>
> Resolved by editing the
>   \updates\concrete5.6.x.x\concrete\core\controllers\blocks\guestbook.php,
>   changing  protected $btIncludeAll = true; to protected $btIncludeAll =
>   1;

Found [here](http://www.concrete5.org/developers/bugs/5-6-3-2/upgrade-from-5.6.2.1-fail-on-guestbook-refresh/)